# simplexml, returning multiple items with the same tag

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML file loaded into php simplexml.

```
<adf>
<prospect>
<customer>
<name part="first">Bob</name>
<name part="last">Smith</name>
</customer>
</prospect>
</adf>
```

using

```
$customers = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
```

This will return "Bob" but how do I return the last name?

```
echo $customers->prospect[0]->customer->contact->name;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the different `<name>` elements by number, using array-style syntax.

```
$names = $customers->prospect[0]->customer->name;

echo $names[0]; // Bob
echo $names[1]; // Smith
```

In fact, you're *already* doing it for the `<prospect>` element!

See also [*Basic SimpleXML Usage*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) in the manual.

---

If you want to select elements based on some criteria, then [*XPath*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is the tool to use.

```
$customer   = $customers->prospect[0]->customer;
$last_names = $customer->xpath('name[@part="last"]'); // always returns an array
echo $last_names[0]; // Smith
```